# Cached XML for PHP?

Tags: php, xml, caching, simplexml

I have a custom PHP framework and am discovering the joys of storing configuration settings as human-readable, simple XML.

I am very tempted to introduce XML (really simple XML, like this)

```
<mainmenu>
 <button action="back" label="Back"/>
 <button action="new" label="New item"/>
</mainmenu>
```

in a number of places in the framework. It is just so much more fun to read, maintain and extend. Until now, configuration was done using

```
name=value;name=value;name=value;
```

pairs, arrays, collections of variables, and so on.

However, I fear for the framework's performance. While the individual XML operations amount to next to nothing in profiling, they are of course more expensive than a simple explode() on a big string. I feel uncomfortable with simpleXML (my library of choice) doing a full well-formedness check on a dozen of XML chunks every time the user loads a page.

I could cache the XML objects myself but would like to 1.) avoid the hassle and 2.) not add to the framework's complexity.

I am therefore looking for an unobtrusive XML "caching" solution. The perfect thing would be a function that I can give a file path, and returns a parsed simpleXML object. Internally, it maintains a cache somewhere with serialized simpleXML objects or whatever.

Does anybody know tools to do this?

No extension-dependent solutions please, as the framework is designed to run in shared webhosting environments (which is the reason why performance matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the XML into your former format once and then check for modification time of the XML and the text file via `filemtime`. If XML is newer than the textfile, then do the transformation again.

This would increase complexity in a way, but on the other hand would help you reuse your existing code. Of course, caching is another viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i'm useing the Zend Cache for those kind of things and must say it's very fast got one page from about 2secs to 0.5secs down.